# Google App Engine KeyProperty Trouble to use it

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, key

I actually code a web service, in python, and I can't store a value into KeyProperty value. I had a relation one-to-many (Item -> Category). I Want to store my category ID into category field in Item class. Here's my code :

```
class Item(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    desc = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    price = ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)
    category = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Categorie', repeated=True)

class Category(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
```

class ItemHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

```
def insert(self, item_ID):
    try:
        keyItem = ndb.Key('Item', item_ID)
        item = keyItem.get()

        if item is None:
            status = 201
            item = Item(key=keyItem)
        else:
            status = 200

        dict = json.loads(self.request.body)

        keyCategory = ndb.Key('Category', dict['category'])
        cat = ndb.Key('Categorie', item_dict_in['categorie']).get()

        # If data doesn't exist, I insert it
        if cat is None:

            cat.name = dict['categorie']
            me.put();
# continue, all work fine after to write the output.
```

Did someone can help me?

Tancks

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example and also explain what the actual problem is.  E.g., what is the error message.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly however your model is named "Category" but you defined your KeyProperty with "Categorie" kind, so it won't work.